# Problem adding sharepoint group in list item on itemupdated event

Tags: event-receivers

I have this code below and I am trying to add a sharepoint group to an item in a list in itemUpdated event handler. the problem is that the update never happens. The problem is with this line of code properties.ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);

When I debug my code that's where the debugger stops and finishes. So it does not reach the update method. So no group has been added to the item's permission list.

When I remove it, (properties.ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment)), the update happens but I have to refresh the page twice to see the update in the title, for example.

Any idea how can I sovle this?

Here is the code that I am using, together with a class that handles the event firing. I removed the class too but nothing happend.

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {


  base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            using (DisableEventFiring scope = new DisableEventFiring())
            {


               SPWeb web = properties.ListItem.Web;

               SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["HRTR"];
                SPPrincipal principal = (SPPrincipal)group;
                SPRoleAssignment rAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);

               properties.ListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                properties.ListItem.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                properties.ListItem["Title"] = "A cool new title!" + DateTime.Now;
                properties.ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);

               properties.ListItem.Update();
                properties.ListItem.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

           }

}

-----------

    class DisableEventFiring : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable 
    {
         // Boolean to hold the original value of the EventFiringEnabled property          
         bool  _originalValue;
         public DisableEventFiring()          
        {              
            // Save off the original value of EventFiringEnabled               
            _originalValue = base.EventFiringEnabled;               
            // Set EventFiringEnabled to false to disable it              
            base .EventFiringEnabled = false ;          
        }           
        public  void  Dispose()          
        {              
            // Set EventFiringEnabled back to its original value               
            base.EventFiringEnabled = _originalValue;          
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not added any role definition for the role assignment. Below is a sample code

```
    base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilages(() =>
{
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.Web.Url))
{
   using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
   {
      SPList list = web.Lists[properties.List.Title]
      SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

      if(!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
      {
          item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
      }

      SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["TestGroup"];
      SPRoleAssignment role = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
      SPRoleDefinition definition = item.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
      role.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(definition);

      item.RoleAssignments.Add(role);
      item.Update()
   }
 }
});

base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Good catch on not actually assigning any role. Your code sample won't quite work though, as you need to re-load the item from a context created inside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges block for the elevated privileges to take effect.

Comment: You are right. Fixed the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Could give you some suggestion.

1) Try out if you get some exception using try catch in the line

```
properties.ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(rAssignment);
```

2) Instead of using ListItem.Update(); try to use ListItem.SystemUpdate(false);

3) In the EventReceiver use the following method to update

```
Comment these lines available in the EventReceiver

       base.ItemUpdated(properties);
       base.ItemUpdating(properties);
       base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

for updating use the following method

        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
        try
        {
            ListItem.SystemUpdate(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Prasath, I used the try/catch block and it gives me Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: it is giving me an error with httpContext.Current.Session and it is the same: Object not set to an instance on an object.

Answer (score 0):

Unless all of the users of the list have the ability to modify permissions, you will need to use [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) or some other method to get higher permissions. Inside that method, you need to re-load the site/web/ListItem for the higher permissions to take effect.

Also - I doubt it's causing a problem, but making a DisableEventFiring class is more something you do to get that functionality somewhere other than an event receiver. Inside an event receiver you can just call the properties directly.